# ¿Cómo alojar API Rest Golang en algun servidor web?

Tags: rest, go, host

Necesito desplegar/hostear/alojar una `API Rest` que esta desarrollada en `Golang` en algún cloud computing libre **(AWS, Google App Engine, etc)** para luego ser consumido desde `Postman` o algún otro software parecido.

Actualmente estoy consumiendo el servicio con algo que se llama `labstack/echo` pero creo que eso es para hacer pruebas locales sino me equivoco.

Soy nuevo con `Golang` y estoy haciendo un *challenge* para `MercadoLibre`, necesitaría una ayuda para terminarlo...